# Getting exception in app.xaml.cs file before set main page checking the condition

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need to check the condition in app.xaml.cs file based on that result set the main page but I am getting internal inconsistance exception. Please suggest any idea for dynamically setting the main page. Thanks in advance.

Here is my sample code:

```
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _loginView = new SampleView();

       InitializePage();

    }

    private async void InitializePage()
    {
        await LocalDatabaseService.Instance.Initialize();

        var applicationEntity = await LocalDatabaseService.Instance.GetUserApplicationRecord();

        MainPage = applicationEntity != null ? new NavigationPage(new SampleTwo()) : new NavigationPage(_loginView);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

[The `MainPage` property should be set in the App constructor](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/application-class/)

Since `InitializePage` is running asynchronously, the `MainPage` won't be set immediately in the `App`'s constructor.  I suggest setting the `MainPage` in the constructor to an intermediary "loading" page, and then replace it once you've finished initializing.

Comment: Thanks Damian, That's a great idea but little bit concern about that. I have already splash screen my application, If we include this type page also not seems good I think.

Comment: Perhaps try setting the "loading" page to have the same image as the your splash screen so that users don't see two different screens?

Comment: Thank damian, It mostly solve my problem but still facing some issue. In my splash screen have many different size images are present because suitable to IPad, IOS and Android but When set launch screen image as background image of loading page, it's differ the splash screen image and loading page image.